# Find the double integral that will calculate this volume

Tags: integration, volume

> Find the double integral that will calculate the volume of the solid $f(x,y) = (x^2)+4y^3$ in the region created by the points $(0,0),(1,0),(0,2).$

This is what I got but I dont know if my interpretation is correct:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2-2x}(x^2+4y^3)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, you've done it correctly.  You translated "the triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,2)" to the parametrization y = 0 to 2-2x for x = 0 to 1.  Then you integrated the function over that region.

Comment: Your description of the solid is not clear. Do you mean
$$\{(x,y,z)\Bbb R^3\mid (x,y)\in T\text{ and }0\le z\le x^2+4y^3\}$$ where $T\subset\Bbb R^2$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (0,2)?$